How to run a PowerShell script during MSI install that accepts command line parameters
I need to pass 2 parameters to an MSI when installing an electron app from the command line. For example:
msiexec /i "C:\example\filepath\ExampleAppInstaller.msi" USERID="1234" APIKEY="5678" /quiet
I want the MSI to run a powershell script that saves these parameters in a temporary file on the user's computer sometime during the install process. When the application runs for the first time after install it will read from the temporary file and use the parameters in the app.
The part that I am having trouble with is creating the Custom Action in the MSI that will run the PowerShell script that creates the temporary file. I have tried using the Wix toolset, but I can't get it to work. I have Wix version 5.0.1+2f00cbe6.
Here is the PowerShell script that I am trying to run during the MSI install (named 'writeParams.ps1'):
param(
    [string]$UserID,
    [string]$ApiKey
)

# Define the folder and file paths dynamically using the environment variable
$AppDataFolder = "$env:APPDATA\ExampleAppTest"
$filePath = "$AppDataFolder\installParams.json"

# Check if the folder exists, if not, create it
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $AppDataFolder)) {
    New-Item -Path $AppDataFolder -ItemType Directory
}

# Create the JSON content with the provided parameters
$jsonContent = @{
    userId = $UserID
    apiKey = $ApiKey
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Write the JSON content to the file
$jsonContent | Out-File -FilePath $filePath

# Exit with a success code
exit 0

I have tried building the MSI using a .wixproj file. Here my ExampleAppProject.wixproj file:
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/5.0.1">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
    <WixOutputName>ExampleAppInstaller</WixOutputName>
    <WixOutputType>MSI</WixOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <WixSource Include="Product.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


And here is my Product.wxs file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">

  <!-- Product Information -->
  <Product Id="*" Name="ExampleApp" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Example" UpgradeCode="86a341fc-f2ff-4fc6-9627-8127bb1efc68">
    <Package InstallerVersion="500" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <!-- Media element defines the cabinet file -->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <!-- Directories define the installation path -->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="ExampleApp"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <!-- Feature defines what will be installed -->
    <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <!-- Define the files to be installed -->
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="PowerShellComponent" Guid="1e20057b-3f79-4258-b054-27767beb202c">
        <File Id="PowerShellScript" Source="writeParams.ps1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>

  <!-- ComponentGroup for grouping components -->
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents">
      <ComponentRef Id="PowerShellComponent"/>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

  <!-- Define the custom action to run the PowerShell script -->
  <Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="RunPowerShellScript"
                  Property="powershell.exe"
                  ExeCommand="-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]writeParams.ps1&quot; -UserID [USERID] -ApiKey [APIKEY]"
                  Execute="deferred"
                  Return="check"
                  Impersonate="no"/>

    <!-- Run the custom action after the installation files are copied -->
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="RunPowerShellScript" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>


I've been stuck on this for a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

What's the problem?

tl;dr: Your PowerShell script refers to a user-specific environment variable $env:APPDATA, but the custom action is run without impersonation. This causes you script to be run in the context of the local system user, writing the JSON to a different path than intended.
The hotfix would be to set Impersonate="yes" on the custom action, but as your product is installed for all users (InstallScope="perMachine"), the fix will only work for the specific use case that the installing user is identical to the user that will actually use the software (which typically isn't the case in corporate environments where software is installed by admins or even in home use, when multiple persons are using the same computer).
Changing to an actual per-user installation (InstallScope="perUser") might be a more sensible fix.

The following suggestions are intended to help you diagnose PowerShell custom action issues more easily in the future.
PowerShell Custom Action
For running PowerShell scripts I strongly recommend to use the quiet execution custom actions (note the different action names for WiX v3 and v4/5).
Advantages:

Prevents the brief popup of the console window - a problem that persists even when using parameter -WindowStyle hidden with powershell.exe.
Redirects all PowerShell output to the MSI log, so logging can be done through simple Write-Host statements.

PowerShell script suggestions
Best practice for PowerShell scripts is to set $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' as early as possible in the script, so errors won't go by unnoticed. The effect is that any error is automatically turned into a script-terminating error, which causes a PowerShell exit code that is different from zero, so Windows Installer can detect and report the error.
In cases where you want to selectively suppress script-terminating errors (typically for explicit testing in conditions), you would pass -ErrorAction Continue (to report the error and continue) or -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue (to continue without reporting) to individual commands.
Specify parameters as mandatory for all required parameters, to detect mistakes in argument passing.
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)
    [string]$UserID,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)
    [string]$ApiKey
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# The logging automatically ends up in the MSI log
Write-Host "PowerShell script received these args: UserId=$UserID, ApiKey=$ApiKey"

# remaining code

Write a verbose MSI log
Call msiexec with parameter /l*v LOGPATH to write a verbose log, which will include the PowerShell script's log messages:
msiexec /i "C:\example\filepath\ExampleAppInstaller.msi" USERID="1234" APIKEY="5678" /quiet /l*v "c:\example\filepath\ExampleAppInstaller.log"

